# Alternativas similares como Evento Load en MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

Estoy trabajando recién en MVC y quisiera consultar como puedo ejecutar consultas automáticas al abrir una página en mi proyecto MVC 5, algo similar como el `PageLoad` o Evento `Load` de .NET.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Por el propio concepto de MVC la llamada al controlador se trata como "PageLoad" puesto que llamas al controlador y trabajas allí los datos que quieras antes de mandarlos a la vista y mostrarlos al usuario, luego simplemente tienes que devolver el modelo a la vista o pasar los datos que sean necesarios en el ViewBag, mostrando al usuario el resultado procesado de la vista como deseas después de la carga y procesado de datos. No se si solucionará tu problema.

Un saludo

Comment: Si me ayuda colega, pensaba en eso y lo puse en práctica y me viene funcionado.. Gracias.